# Chat not closing and not showing response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chat, bots

I made a qnamaker service and build a chat to show the response of the question.

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Live Chat</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="chat.js"></script>
    <script src="rispostachat.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chat.css">
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="live-chat">

        <header class="clearfix">

            <a href="#" class="chat-close">x</a>

            <h4>Bot</h4>


        </header>

        <div class="chat">

                      <h3>Risposta:</h3>
                      <div id="answer"></div>

            <input type="text" id="question" name="question">
<button type="button" class="button" id="post-btn"> Chiedi</button>
</br>



</body>
</html>
```

This is for close and show the chat box

```
    (function() {

    $('#live-chat header').on('click', function() {

        $('.chat').slideToggle(300, 'swing');


    });

    $('.chat-close').on('click', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $('#live-chat').fadeOut(300);

    });

}) ();
```

And this is for take the response inserted and show the response to the user

```
    $("#post-btn").click(function(){
     jQuery.ajax ({
        url: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v2.0/knowledgebases/idknowledgebasetoinsert/generateAnswer",
        type: "POST",
        data: '{"question" : "'+$("#question").val()+'"}',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType : "application/json",
        headers: {"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "subscriptionkeytoinsert"},
        success: function(msg, status, jqXHR){
             $('#answer').html(msg.answers[0].answer);
        }
     });  
  });
```

When i click on the header of the chat , the chat not close and the chat not disappear when i clcik on the close button x of the chat.
When i click on Chiedi to send the answer nothing happen. I don't see the response of the service in the chat.

Comment: Do you see any console errors in the browser?

Comment: Why there are 2 versions of `jquery` included?

Comment: No i don't see any errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have included the jQuery twice (2 different versions) in your header

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'l try to remove a jquery.